Prevent a device from going to sleep when browsing a web page
I would like to prevent the device going to sleep while looking at my web page. I would like this to work for chrome and safari on both ios and andriod.
I have currently researched 2 possible options for this.

Wavelock API This seems promising as the browser supports it natively. But does does not seem to be supported by many browsers just yet. Has anyone had succsess with this yet?
NoSleep.js Seems widely used, but has many open. It has not had a commit for over 4 years. It seems to work by playing a hidden video on the webpage. It seems to have fallen into disrepair.

This stackover questions top answer no longer works on chrome on andrioid. And its second best answer suggests NoSleep.
In this answer on stack overflow it suggests the wavelock API but also notes that this into supported properly on IOS.

While the topic (subject matter) of your question is fine, there are a few nuances. "Has anyone had success" is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow, because it invites a discussion. Similarly, "are there other options" is generally too open-ended to make a good SO question. You should simply ask how to solve the problem you want to solve (which is what the first part of your question did pretty well, if you leave off the bolded questions at the end). To me, it looks like that question has already been asked and answered at least once.

If you have specific questions about a particular option, like NoSleep.js, then ask a question specifically about that. But note that "I'm worried it will fall into disrepair" isn't really something that anyone here on SO can help you with.
